# What is this quad-jet plane at El Paso Airport?

Tags: aircraft-identification

If you look at El Paso International Airport on [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Sierra+West+Airlines/@31.7947067,-106.3866196,60m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x1f2f4f000097b549!2sEl+Paso+International+Airport!8m2!3d31.8053354!4d-106.3824345!3m4!1s0x86e75af014d68dab:0xb39089e5859e16c3!8m2!3d31.7929551!4d-106.3863364), on the south side apron and across from a hangar that is labeled "Sierra West Airlines" (west of the NASA facilities) there is a small quad-jet plane:

The aircraft is about 20 m long and has a wing span of about 18 m:

[image: aircraft]

Any idea on what this is?

Comment: I added an image from Google maps, I guess this is the one you were talking about?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This appears to be a [McDonnell 119/220](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_119), a 1950s vintage business jet attempt (from before McDonnell merged with Douglas).  The four engine layout with engines under the wings, coupled with the size, is very distinctive.

The one at El Paso is apparently a genuine rarity — there was only a single unit (the prototype) ever constructed.

Answer (score 105):

It's *the* [McDonnell 220](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_119), registration N4AZ.

[image]
[(Source)](https://www.flickr.com/photos/royalscottking/35081822990)

Wiki says

> The McDonnell 119/220 was an attempt at making a business jet by McDonnell Aircraft in the late-1950s. It had a configuration that was unique by bizjet standards, with four jet engines mounted in individual pods underneath a low wing; it could accommodate ten passengers in a luxury executive configuration but could carry as many as 26.
>
> ...
>
> The McDonnell Corporation used the airplane as a VIP transport for a few years before donating it to the Flight Safety Foundation's research facility in Phoenix, Arizona. As of 2020 the single prototype is still extant, **registered as N4AZ and stored at El Paso International Airport**.

Only one such plane exists. Its first flight was in 1959.

[Here](https://images.app.goo.gl/1E936EhaXC7Un2mZ6) are some pictures.

Comment: good god that had to guzzle some gas, although not much different than a Jetstar. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: 'Dale King'  was impressed that you and Zeiss Ikon (25 seconds after you :-) )  were able to produce that answer so well and rapidly. He said:
"Signed up just to say how next level the internet is. You can just post a picture of a pixelated plane and within an hour someone tells you what it is." What a time to be alive.

Comment: @WilliamTaft According to the Wikipedia article we both linked, it appears that it was in direct competition with the Jetstar for a military light transport contract (the kind now held by VC-20).  It was 1959, so anything with jet engines needed big tanks to have range...

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I was similarly impressed by the answers to a [question I asked](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/66978/1485) last summer. The user [DeepSpace](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/3363/deepspace) could within short time identify and produce *the flight path* of the plane I had observed. I know that's commonplace for you guys;  but to me as an aviation layman but computer guy it is an indication for the scope of the information age, the level of transparency we are heading towards  and the corresponding disappearance of privacy.